# Replacing value in array if matches specific search term - O(n^2)

Tags: c#

My problem essentially is, I have an array of ArtistNames, these are search terms that i will be sending off to an API these names are crawled from a web page but the names returned sometimes don't match the artist names in the api.

My work around was to create an 'EdgeCase' object that contains the FestivalID, SearchTerm(Api search term) and a string to compare against.

My code essentially loops through the artists, inside of that it loops through the edge cases to see if the artistName is contained within an edge case.  I'm removing the edge case from the array once found but it still doesn't improve efficiency.

```
       List<EdgeCases> edgeCases = _currentActiveData.EdgeCases.Where(x => x.FestivalID == festivalID).ToList();
        //Todo Improve performance
        for (int i = 0; i < artistNames.Length; i++)
        {
            for (var j = 0; i < edgeCases.Count; j++)
            {
                EdgeCases edgeCase = edgeCases[j];
                if (artistNames[i].Trim().Contains(edgeCase.ComparableString))
                {
                    artistNames[i] = edgeCase.SearchTerm;
                    edgeCases.Remove(edgeCases[j]);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Typo on the inner loop? it's using `i` in the `for`'s condition and increment.

Comment: inner loop is also skipping edge cases in the cases where it does remove one

Comment: @PhilM Ah, yeah looking at it now.. there are some flaws. It might be worth me attempting to rewrite

Comment: Actually, if you assume that only one edge case will apply to an artist, you can just break from that inner loop after removing.

Comment: Any reason you wouldn't want to have an edge case `Dictionary` instead of a `List`? This way you could have O(1) access and reduce the problem to O(n). Also, keep in mind that the `.Contains` and `.Remove` there are also O(n), _not_ having them might actually improve your overall performance for some cases.

Comment: @GBrandt oh my god, Dictionaries! Honestly, that has solved all of my problems. Thank you for suggesting it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved on the comments, just formalizing:  Use a `Dictionary`.

The whole problem with Lists there is that you have to traverse them to find what you want, while you could have that in constant time (and way less code) with a `Dictionary`.

It's relevant to note that this approach would not fit if the criteria for an Actor name to fall into an edge case was more complex, in which case I think O(n²) is actually the best you can get unless you can apply binary search or something to find the edge cases.

Comment: I'm failing to see how a Dictionary helps in this case, given that it looks like substrings are needed, rather than finding by the actual artist name. What am I missing?